# Making a invisible grip to resize

Tags: c++, qt

All around my frameless widget I have defined thin labels that work as a grab handle for resizing. The resizing does work. Now I would like to make them invisible (so that you can see what is behind it, e.g. the desktop) but still grab-able for resizing. How is this possible, or is there a better way for resizing a frameless window? Perhaps no need for labels at all?

[image]

Comment: Invisible handles will be quite surprising for users. I'm not sure that's a good idea. May be you should use `QSizeGrip`. It already has resizing functionality and it's appearance are consistent with system style.

Comment: But a `QSizeGrip` is only on the bottom right in the status bar, my widget should behave like a standard window that you can resize whichever edge you grap on